# Mysql - finding duplicate values then only returning latest one then ignore it if it returns a certain result

Tags: php, mysql

I have

```
Tablename
id     coid     name     test     passfail     testdate
VALUES
1       1       Chris    mod1     fail         2015-05-20
2       1       Chris    mod1     pass         2015-05-25
3       2       Patrick  mod1     fail         2015-06-10
4       3       James    mod1                  2015-12-21
5       4       Agnes    mod1     cancelled    2015-07-01
6       5       Freya    mod1     pass         2015-07-01
7       5       Freya    mod2     pass        2015-07-05
```

It lists who has done what test and when, and also if they passed or not.
I need to be able to return the results of the people who have not passed the the mod1 test.

if I use

```
SELECT *
FROM `tablename` 
WHERE `test` = 'mod1' AND `passfail` != 'pass'
```

Chris is in the results because he has also failed the mod1, but i need to be able to ignore the fail because he has passed now.

The results I am after are...

```
3       2       Patrick  mod1     fail         2015-06-10
4       3       James    mod1                  2015-12-21
5       4       Agnes    mod1     cancelled    2015-07-01
```

The `coid` is the Contact ID just in case i get two people with the same name.

If I could find duplicate `coid`'s that have done a mod1 then take the one latest date, and then check to see if it is a pass or not. I think that should give me the results i need,  I have no idea how to do it though... please help

I have been trying all sorts of things on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b740/18)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE coid NOT IN (
    SELECT coid 
    FROM same_table_name 
    WHERE test = 'mod1' AND passfail = 'pass'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out this:

```
 select * from table_name t1 
 inner join (select max(id)as id from table_name group by coid) as t2
 on t1.id=t2.id;
```

You can put any where conditions inside the subquery

Comment: Thank you for the help, I added the conditions but i couldn't seem to get the right results.

Answer (score 1):

I would think a `GROUP BY` would provide the data but I'm not sure as I don't have your data set

```
SELECT *
FROM `tablename` 
WHERE `test` = 'mod1' AND `passfail` != 'pass'
GROUP BY coid
ORDER BY testdate DESC
```

In theory this should grab the latest `coid`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I could not get this to work as I kept getting an error with the 'group by' part, not sure why... syntax is not something i'm good at yet.

Comment: @Leo I got them backwards. GROUP and ORDER have to be in a certain order. Sorry about that

Comment: no problem, i have some other similar select queries i need to do, so i might need this too.